# Strange python error I have never seen before while using pygame

Tags: python, ubuntu, pygame

This error occured while trying to add a sound file to my pygame game.

This error does not occure when I comment out
`self.pong = pygame.mixer.Sound("pingpong.wav")`
on line 34 of my file:

```
import sys, pygame
from pygame.locals import *


class game():

    def __init__(self):

        pygame.init()
        pygame.font.init()
        pygame.mixer.init()

        # set key hold down repeat

        pygame.key.set_repeat(2,2)

        # Image Sizes and positions and movement speeds
        self.lives_size = 700, 200
        self.padle_size = [50,10]
        self.padle_pos  = [350, 685]
        self.game_size = self.width, self.height = 700,700
        self.gButton_pos = [150, 300 ]
        self.gButton_size = [100, 50]
        self.rButton_pos = [450, 300]
        self.rButton_size = [100, 50]

        # Balls Movement Speed
        # Note: this is confusing because its both speed AND direction
        self.speedX = -2     # X coordinate movement for ball
        self.speedY = 1      # Y coordinate movement for ball
        self.speed = [self.speedX, self.speedY]  # Total ball Movement speed

        # Sound effects
        self.pong = pygame.mixer.Sound("pingpong.wav")

        # Number of lives
        self.num_lives = 1

        # Colors, RGB values
        self.white = 255, 255, 255
        self.black = 0, 0, 0
        self.red = 200,0,0
        self.green = 0,200,0
        self.b_red = 255,0,0
        self.b_green = 0,255,0

        # Font style and display
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont("Verdona", 24)
        self.font_color = self.black
        self.font_background = self.white

        # game state
        self.pause = False



        # Label area where lives are displayed
        # Game over display not currently working
        self.display_lives = pygame.display.set_mode(self.lives_size)


        # Main Window for game... Wierd spot for it
        self.main_window = pygame.display.set_mode((700,720))

        # Game play Window
        self.screen = pygame.Surface((self.game_size))
        self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()

        # Make game oover window image
        #game_over = pygame.display.set_mode((200,200))
        #gameover_rect = self.game_over.get_rect()

        # Importing ball Image
        self.ball = pygame.image.load("redball2.png")
        self.ballrect = self.ball.get_rect()


    def textObjects(self, text, font):
        textSurface = font.render(text, True, self.black)
        return  textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

    def Button(self, msg, color, b_color, x,y, w,h, action = None):

        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        print(mouse)


       # identify button boundry

        boundry = x + w > mouse[0] > x and y + h > mouse[1] > y

        # button image / active vs inactives

        if boundry is True:

            pygame.draw.rect(self.main_window, b_color, Rect((x,y), (w,h)))

            if click[0] == 1 and action != None:

                if action == "start":
                    self.num_lives = 5
                    self.game_loop()

                elif action == "quit":
                    pygame.quit()


        else:

            pygame.draw.rect(self.main_window, color, Rect((x,y), (w,h)))

        text = pygame.font.SysFont("Verdona", 40)
        textSurface, textRect = self.textObjects(msg, text)
        self.main_window.blit(textSurface, (x, y),textRect)




    def paddle(self):

        # make the padle
        # This is the pygame Drawing function
        paddle = pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.black,
                Rect(self.padle_pos, self.padle_size))
        return paddle


    def moveBall(self):
        # Doesn't only move ball
        # updates lives
        # places windows

        # Fill main window color Black
        self.main_window.fill((self.black))

        # place the game play window on main window
        self.main_window.blit(self.screen, (0,20), self.screen_rect)

        # Show Lives
        lives = "lives left: {}".format(self.num_lives)
        label = self.font.render(
                lives,         # The string to render
                1,             # With anti aliasing
                self.font_color,
                self.font_background)

        # Make lives display an image object
        label_rect = label.get_rect()

        # place the lives display on the window made for it
        self.display_lives.blit(label, (300, 0),label_rect)


        # place the game play window on main window
        self.main_window.blit(self.screen, (0,20), self.screen_rect)
        # place the lives display on the window made for it
        self.screen.fill(self.white)

        #place the ball on the screen
        self.screen.blit(self.ball, self.ballrect)
        pygame.display.flip()

    def hitPadle(self):
        pass

    def gameOver(self):

        self.screen.fill((self.white))
        self.main_window.blit(self.screen, (0,20), self.screen_rect)


        while True:

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                #print(event)
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    #quit()

            self.Button("AGAIN!",self.green, self.b_green, 150,300, 100,50, "start")
            self.Button("QUIT",self.red, self.b_red, 450,300, 100,50, "quit")


            pygame.display.flip()


    def paused(self):

            #largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",115)
            #TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Paused", largeText)
            #TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
            #gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

            while self.pause:

                for event in pygame.event.get():

                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        pygame.quit()
                        quit()

                    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                        if event.key == K_c:
                            self.pause = False
                            break



    def game_loop(self):

        # OK here we go
        # Ignore ALL  print statements, they are there for debug

        # make some variables to help direction changes
        change_direction = False
        speedX = 2
        speedY = 2
        go_right = 1
        go_left = 2
        direction_change = 0

        # MAIN EVENT LOOP
        while True:

            # Event testing loop

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                #print(event)

                #condition to exit
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()

                # Conditions for handling the paddle

                # Test if a key is pressed
                if event.type == KEYUP:
                    # If not, paddle not moving, ball direction uneffected
                    change_direction = False
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

                    # See which key is pressed
                    # If yes, paddle moving, change ball direction accordingly
                    if  event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        change_direction = True
                        # make variable for which way to change direction
                        direction_change = go_right
                        # This Condition keeps the paddle on screen
                        if self.padle_pos[0] > self.width-self.padle_size[0]:
                            self.padle_pos[0]+=0
                        else:
                            self.padle_pos[0] += 5

                    # Same as previous If nest, but opposit direction
                    if  event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        change_direction = True
                        direction_change = go_left
                        if self.padle_pos[0] < 0:
                            self.padle_pos[0]+=0
                        else:
                            self.padle_pos[0] -= 5

                    # Pause game key (p), press (c) to continue. 
                    #    see paused() method
                    if event.key == K_p:
                        self.pause = True
                        self.paused()


            # Put the paddle on screen
            paddle = self.paddle()

            # Ignore
            #self.movePaddle()

            if  self.num_lives == 0:

                print('='*30,'\n','='*30)
                #self.pause = True
                #self.paused()
                self.gameOver()

            # Move Ball

            #print (self.speed)
            # This is the Pygame function that makes the ball move
            self.ballrect = self.ballrect.move(self.speed)

            # Test if ball hits wall, cieling or floor and inverts direction
            if self.ballrect.left < 0 or self.ballrect.right > self.width:
                self.speed[0] = -self.speed[0]
                print("hit side",self.speed)

            if self.ballrect.top < 0 or self.ballrect.bottom > self.height:
                self.speed[1] = -self.speed[1]

            # Print speed at top screen bounce for debugging
            if self.ballrect.top < 0:
                print('hit top ', self.speed)


            # Yay pygame collision testing
            # Test if ball collides with paddle
            if self.ballrect.colliderect(paddle):
                print('good hit')
                pygame.mixer.Sound.play(self.pong)

                # Conditions for how to adjust ball speed `self.speed` var
                # Should adujust speed AND invert direction
                # Currently not working properly, However I do have it working
                # much better now and not quite as worried.

                    # 1) When moving left, ball sometimes is not inverted (bounced
                    #    up) and life is lost, Ball usually goes throug paddle and often
                    #    becomes stuck and game ends immediatly.

                    # 2) Occasionally ball inverts in wrong direction????
                    #    switch from -1>>0>>1 and visa versa is probably
                    #    creating something wierd here.

                    # 3) Speed Fluctuates seemingly at random, could be lag
                    #
                    #

                if change_direction is True:
                    print('change direction', self.speed)
                    # Changes the X coordinate in speed to a negative (inverts)
                    #print(self.speed)

                    if direction_change == go_right:
                        speedX += 1
                        speedY -= 1
                        self.speed = [speedX, speedY]
                        direction_change = 0
                        print('change right', self.speed)

                    elif direction_change == go_left:
                        speedX -= 1
                        speedY += 1
                        self.speed = [speedX, speedY]
                        direction_change = 0
                        print('change left', self.speed)

                    else: self.speed = self.speed
                    # This is what creates the bounce effect
                    self.speed[1] = -self.speed[1]
                    print('after bounce', self.speed)

                else:
                    self.speed[1] = -self.speed[1]
                    print('direction constant', self.speed)

            # Life lost if ball hits bottom of screen
            if self.ballrect.bottom > self.height:
                print('hit bottom',self.speed)
                self.num_lives-=1
                print(self.num_lives)


            self.moveBall()

game = game()
game.game_loop()
```

Here is the opening line to the standard error output:

`*** Error in 'python3': double free or corruption (top): 0x0000000000f20d90 ***`

Then there is a very long backtrace, and an even longer 'memory map'

The very last line in the error end with

`Aborted (core dumped)`

Here is the full error:

```
*** Error in `python3': double free or corruption (top): 0x0000000000f20d90 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7f430a5b07e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7fe0a)[0x7f430a5b8e0a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7f430a5bc98c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(fclose+0x103)[0x7f430a5a6363]
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pygame/.libs/libSDL-1-9a9431b0.2.so.0.11.4(+0xf539)[0x7f4308b18539]
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pygame/.libs/libSDL_mixer-1-ec459934.2.so.0.12.0(Mix_LoadWAV_RW+0xe6)[0x7f4304288da6]
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pygame/mixer.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0x4626)[0x7f4301762626]
python3[0x55d17c]
python3(PyObject_Call+0x47)[0x5b7167]
python3(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x4f06)[0x528d06]
python3(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x13b)[0x52e12b]
python3[0x4ebcc3]
python3(PyObject_Call+0x47)[0x5b7167]
python3[0x4f413e]
python3(PyObject_Call+0x47)[0x5b7167]
python3[0x54d359]
python3[0x55d17c]
python3(PyObject_Call+0x47)[0x5b7167]
python3(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x4f06)[0x528d06]
python3[0x52d2e3]
python3(PyEval_EvalCode+0x1f)[0x52dfdf]
python3[0x5fd2c2]
python3(PyRun_FileExFlags+0x9a)[0x5ff76a]
python3(PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags+0x1bc)[0x5ff95c]
python3(Py_Main+0x456)[0x63e7d6]
python3(main+0xe1)[0x4cfe41]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f430a559830]
python3(_start+0x29)[0x5d5f29]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-007a8000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 50596143                           /usr/bin/python3.5
009a8000-009aa000 r--p 003a8000 08:01 50596143                           /usr/bin/python3.5
009aa000-00a41000 rw-p 003aa000 08:01 50596143                           /usr/bin/python3.5
00a41000-00a72000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00cec000-00f2c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f42e0000000-7f42e0021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f42e0021000-7f42e4000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f42e8000000-7f42e8021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f42e8021000-7f42ec000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f42ef7fe000-7f42ef7ff000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f42ef7ff000-7f42effff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f42effff000-7f42f4000000 rw-s 00000000 00:14 10                         /dev/shm/pulse-shm-2867672065
7f42f4000000-7f42f4021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f42f4021000-7f42f8000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f42f83d7000-7f42f83d8000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f42f83d8000-7f42f8bd8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f42f8bd8000-7f42fcbd9000 rw-s 00000000 00:14 24                         /dev/shm/pulse-shm-591135841
7f42fcbd9000-7f42fcbdf000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 50858238                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_pulse.so
7f42fcbdf000-7f42fcdde000 ---p 00006000 08:01 50858238                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_pulse.so
7f42fcdde000-7f42fcddf000 r--p 00005000 08:01 50858238                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_pulse.so
7f42fcddf000-7f42fcde0000 rw-p 00006000 08:01 50858238                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_pulse.so
7f42fcde0000-7f42fce0a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 50602882                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0.4.8
7f42fce0a000-7f42fd00a000 ---p 0002a000 08:01 50602882                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0.4.8
7f42fd00a000-7f42fd00b000 r--p 0002a000 08:01 50602882                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0.4.8
7f42fd00b000-7f42fd00c000 rw-p 0002b000 08:01 50602882                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0.4.8
7f42fd00c000-7f42fd013000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 50602534                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0.8.2
7f42fd013000-7f42fd213000 ---p 00007000 08:01 50602534                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0.8.2
7f42fd213000-7f42fd214000 r--p 00007000 08:01 50602534                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0.8.2
7f42fd214000-7f42fd215000 rw-p 00008000 08:01 50602534                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0.8.2
7f42fd215000-7f42fd227000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 44568911                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.17.0
7f42fd227000-7f42fd427000 ---p 00012000 08:01 44568911                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.17.0
7f42fd427000-7f42fd428000 r--p 00012000 08:01 44568911                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.17.0
7f42fd428000-7f42fd429000 rw-p 00013000 08:01 44568911                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.17.0
7f42fd429000-7f42fd440000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 44564672                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.23.so
7f42fd440000-7f42fd640000 ---p 00017000 08:01 44564672                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.23.so
7f42fd640000-7f42fd641000 r--p 00017000 08:01 44564672                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.23.so
7f42fd641000-7f42fd642000 rw-p 00018000 08:01 44564672                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.23.so
7f42fd642000-7f42fd644000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f42fd644000-7f42fd6d1000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 50602884                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2.0.11
7f42fd6d1000-7f42fd8d0000 ---p 0008d000 08:01 50602884                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2.0.11
7f42fd8d0000-7f42fd8ec000 r--p 0008c000 08:01 50602884                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2.0.11
7f42fd8ec000-7f42fd8ed000 rw-p 000a8000 08:01 50602884                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2.0.11
7f42fd8ed000-7f42fd960000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 50601479                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libFLAC.so.8.3.0
7f42fd960000-7f42fdb60000 ---p 00073000 08:01 50601479                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libFLAC.so.8.3.0
7f42fdb60000-7f42fdb61000 r--p 00073000 08:01 50601479                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libFLAC.so.8.3.0
7f42fdb61000-7f42fdb62000 rw-p 00074000 08:01 50601479                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libFLAC.so.8.3.0
7f42fdb62000-7f42fdb78000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 44564667                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.23.so
7f42fdb78000-7f42fdd77000 ---p 00016000 08:01 44564667                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.23.so
7f42fdd77000-7f42fdd78000 r--p 00015000 08:01 44564667                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.23.so
7f42fdd78000-7f42fdd79000 rw-p 00016000 08:01 44564667                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.23.so
7f42fdd79000-7f42fdd7b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f42fdd7b000-7f42fde53000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 44568780                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20.0.5
7f42fde53000-7f42fe052000 ---p 000d8000 08:01 44568780                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20.0.5
7f42fe052000-7f42fe053000 r--p 000d7000 08:01 44568780                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20.0.5
7f42fe053000-7f42fe05b000 rw-p 000d8000 08:01 44568780                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20.0.5
7f42fe05b000-7f42fe05c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f42fe05c000-7f42fe07d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 44568934                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
7f42fe07d000-7f42fe27c000 ---p 00021000 08:01 44568934                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
7f42fe27c000-7f42fe27d000 r--p 00020000 08:01 44568934                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
7f42fe27d000-7f42fe27e000 rw-p 00021000 08:01 44568934                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
7f42fe27e000-7f42fe29d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 44569025                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
7f42fe29d000-7f42fe49c000 ---p 0001f000 08:01 44569025                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
7f42fe49c000-7f42fe49d000 r--p 0001e000 08:01 44569025                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
7f42fe49d000-7f42fe49e000 rw-p 0001f000 08:01 44569025                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
7f42fe49e000-7f42fe4a0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f42fe4a0000-7f42fe4a5000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 50601729                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasyncns.so.0.3.1
7f42fe4a5000-7f42fe6a4000 ---p 00005000 08:01 50601729                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasyncns.so.0.3.1
7f42fe6a4000-7f42fe6a5000 r--p 00004000 08:01 50601729                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasyncns.so.0.3.1
7f42fe6a5000-7f42fe6a6000 rw-p 00005000 08:01 50601729                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasyncns.so.0.3.1
7f42fe6a6000-7f42fe708000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 50602736                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsndfile.so.1.0.25
7f42fe708000-7f42fe908000 ---p 00062000 08:01 50602736                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsndfile.so.1.0.25
7f42fe908000-7f42fe90a000 r--p 00062000 08:01 50602736                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsndfile.so.1.0.25
7f42fe90a000-7f42fe90b000 rw-p 00064000 08:01 50602736                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsndfile.so.1.0.25
7f42fe90b000-7f42fe90f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f42fe90f000-7f42fe917000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 44569053                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwrap.so.0.7.6
7f42fe917000-7f42feb16000 ---p 00008000 08:01 44569053                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwrap.so.0.7.6
7f42feb16000-7f42feb17000 r--p 00007000 08:01 44569053                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwrap.so.0.7.6
7f42feb17000-7f42feb18000 rw-p 00008000 08:01 44569053                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwrap.so.0.7.6
7f42feb18000-7f42feb19000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f42feb19000-7f42feb99000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 44564494                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0.14.0
7f42feb99000-7f42feb9c000 r--p 0007f000 08:01 44564494                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0.14.0
7f42feb9c000-7f42feb9d000 rw-p 00082000 08:01 44564494                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0.14.0
7f42feb9d000-7f42feb9e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f42feb9e000-7f42febe8000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 44564740                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3.14.6
7f42febe8000-7f42fede8000 ---p 0004a000 08:01 44564740                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3.14.6
7f42fede8000-7f42fede9000 r--p 0004a000 08:01 44564740                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3.14.6
7f42fede9000-7f42fedea000 rw-p 0004b000 08:01 44564740                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3.14.6
7f42fedea000-7f42fee63000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 50858971                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsecommon-8.0.so
7f42fee63000-7f42ff062000 ---p 00079000 08:01 50858971                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsecommon-8.0.so
7f42ff062000-7f42ff063000 r--p 00078000 08:01 50858971                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsecommon-8.0.so
7f42ff063000-7f42ff064000 rw-p 00079000 08:01 50858971                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsecommon-8.0.so
7f42ff064000-7f42ff06e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 44568926                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjson-c.so.2.0.0
7f42ff06e000-7f42ff26d000 ---p 0000a000 08:01 44568926                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjson-c.so.2.0.0
7f42ff26d000-7f42ff26e000 r--p 00009000 08:01 44568926                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjson-c.so.2.0.0
7f42ff26e000-7f42ff26f000 rw-p 0000a000 08:01 44568926                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjson-c.so.2.0.0
7f42ff26f000-7f42ff2bd000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 50602624                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpulse.so.0.19.0
7f42ff2bd000-7f42ff4bc000 ---p 0004e000 08:01 50602624                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpulse.so.0.19.0
7f42ff4bc000-7f42ff4bd000 r--p 0004d000 08:01 50602624                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpulse.so.0.19.0
7f42ff4bd000-7f42ff4be000 rw-p 0004e000 08:01 50602624                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpulse.so.0.19.0
7f42ff6c0000-7f42ff7b9000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 50601719                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0
7f42ff7b9000-7f42ff9b8000 ---p 000f9000 08:01 50601719                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0
7f42ff9b8000-7f42ff9bf000 r--p 000f8000 08:01 50601719                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0
7f42ff9bf000-7f42ff9c0000 rw-p 000ff000 08:01 50601719                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0
7f42ff9c0000-7f42ff9c5000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 50601642                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
7f42ff9c5000-7f42ffbc4000 ---p 00005000 08:01 50601642                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
7f42ffbc4000-7f42ffbc5000 r--p 00004000 08:01 50601642                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
7f42ffbc5000-7f42ffbc6000 rw-p 00005000 08:01 50601642                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
7f42ffbc6000-7f42ffbcf000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 50601660                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1.3.0
7f42ffbcf000-7f42ffdce000 ---p 00009000 08:01 50601660                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1.3.0
7f42ffdce000-7f42ffdcf000 r--p 00008000 08:01 50601660                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1.3.0
7f42ffdcf000-7f42ffdd0000 rw-p 00009000 08:01 50601660                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1.3.0
7f42ffdd0000-7f42ffdd9000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 50601634                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1.0.2
7f42ffdd9000-7f42fffd8000 ---p 00009000 08:01 50601634                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1.0.2
7f42fffd8000-7f42fffd9000 r--p 00008000 08:01 50601634                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1.0.2
7f42fffd9000-7f42fffda000 rw-p 00009000 08:01 50601634                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1.0.2
7f42fffda000-7f42fffeb000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 50601640                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
7f42fffeb000-7f43001ea000 ---p 00011000 08:01 50601640                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
7f43001ea000-7f43001eb000 r--p 00010000 08:01 50601640                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
7f43001eb000-7f43001ec000 rw-p 00011000 08:01 50601640                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0Aborted (core dumped)
```

What is causing this type of error, and how might I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by using a different type of file format.

According to pygame `.wav` and `.mp3` files crash pygame when using Ubuntu.

The correct filetype to use in pygame on Ubuntu is `.ogg`

Answer (score 0):

That happened because of a bug in C code. If your program is pure Python, no error on your part should make that happen, and you found a bug in either Python or Pygame. You should find the smallest possible program you can that still has that bug, and then report it.

Comment: Fascinating, ok then i guess thats what i will do

Comment: where should i report it?

Comment: Did you minimize the test case? If the pygame call is key to triggering it, I'd report it to the pygame developers.